# CMD: extract part of a filename and use it as variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, extract

I ripped my CDs with EAC to CUE+WAV files, added cover art and all my files are in the same folder with filenames pattern "Album artist - Album title", for ex.:

```
Clannad - Legend.wav/cue/jpg
David Bowie - Best Of Bowie [Disc 1].wav/cue/jpg
David Bowie - Best Of Bowie [Disc 2].wav/cue/jpg
```

I'm new to this so I wrote a simple CMD batch to convert my music to FLAC format, but it requires manual copying and pasting of the actual wav/cue/jpg filenames and input of album artist, disc no. and total disc no. for their corresponding tags. It cannot be stored in cuesheet file for some reason, but in my case I have them in filenames as you can see above).

```
ECHO WAV/CUE/JPG FILENAME
SET /P "input="
ECHO ALBUMARTIST
SET /P "albumartist="
ECHO DISCNUMBER
SET /P "discnumber="
ECHO TOTALDISCS
SET /P "totaldiscs="

flac.exe -0 --picture="D:\Music\%input%.jpg" --tag-from-file="CUESHEET=D:\Music\%input%.cue" -T "ALBUMARTIST=%albumartist%" -T "DISCNUMBER=%discnumber%" -T "TOTALDISCS=%totaldiscs%" "D:\Music\%input%.wav"
```

My question is about automation of converting all my ripped albums. How can I extract album artist/disc no./total disc no. info from filenames and loop that for every .wav file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to Magoo's answer, with some bug fixes, and everything is done in one master loop without a CALL. As with Magoo's answer, modify your destination folder at the beginning to suit your needs.

```
@echo off
:: Delayed expansion must be disabled to protect ! when expanding FOR variables.
:: It is normally disabled by default, but I'm making it explicit, just to be sure.
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:: Define where source files are coming from
set "source=D:\Music"

:: Define where output should be stored
set "destination=D:\Music"

pushd "%destination%"

:: Iterate each .wav file (A) and only proceed if .jpg and .cue also exists
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /a-d "%source%\*.wav"') do if exist "%source%\%%~nA.jpg" if exist "%source%\%%~nA.cue" (

  %= Get base name with path, but without extension =%
  set "file=%source%\%%~nA"

  %= Extract "artist - album " (B) and "Disc #" (C) from base name (~nA) =%
  for /f "delims=[] tokens=1,2" %%B in ("%%~nA") do (

    %= Extract "artst " (D) from "artist - abum ". (~nxD) trims trailing space =%
    for /f "delims=-" %%D in ("%%B") do set "artist=%%~nxD"

    %= Extract the number (E) from "Disc #", use 1 as default if not there =%
    set "disc=1"
    for /f "tokens=2" %%E in ("%%C") do set "disc=%%E"

    %= Count the number of discs (F), will be 0 if no [Disc #] =%
    %= The [ is appended to name to prevent something like "Greatest Hits 2" from matching "Greatist Hits" =%
    for /f %%F in ('dir /b /a-d "%source%\%%B[*.wav" 2^>nul ^|find /c /v ""') do set "count=%%F"

    %= temporarily enable delayed expansion to access variables set within loop =%
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

    %= Set count to 1 if no [Disc #] =%
    if !count! equ 0 set /a count=1

    flac.exe -0 --picture="!file!.jpg" --tag-from-file="CUESHEET=!file!.cue" -T "ALBUMARTIST=!artist!" -T "DISCNUMBER=!disc!" -T "TOTALDISCS=!count!" "!file!.wav"

    %= pop the setlocal stack to get back to state at beginning of loop =%
    endlocal
  )
)
popd
```

You may want to add a check to only proceed if the FLAC file does not already exist so you can run the script multiple times without reprocessing files. The outer loop would look something like this, but I can't be sure since I don't know the format of the output file name:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /a-d "%source%\*.wav"') do if exist "%source%\%%~nA.jpg" if exist "%source%\%%~nA.cue" if not exist "%destination%\%%~nA.flac" (
```

---

The logic is much simpler using my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) if you understand regular expressions:

```
@echo off
:: Delayed expansion must be disabled to protect ! when expanding FOR variables.
:: It is normally disabled by default, but I'm making it explicit, just to be sure.
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:: Define where source files are coming from
set "source=D:\music"

:: Define where output should be stored
set "destination=D:\music"

pushd "%destination%"


:: Iterate all *.wav and use JREPL to format result as "fullFileName|artist - album|artist|Disc#"
::                                                      %%A          %%B            %%C    %%D
:: Only proceed if .jpg and .cue also exist
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=|" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d "%source%\*.wav"^|jrepl "^((.+?) - .+?)(?:\[Disc (\d+)])?\.wav$" "$&|$1|$2|$3" /i'
) do if exist "%%~nA.jpg" if exist "%%~nA.cue" (

  %= disc and count are both 1 if %%D is empty =%
  if "%%D" equ "" (
    flac.exe -0 --picture="%source%\%%~nA.jpg" --tag-from-file="CUESHEET=%source%\%%~nA.cue" -T "ALBUMARTIST=%%C" -T "DISCNUMBER=1" -T "TOTALDISCS=1" "%source%\%%A"

  %= else count the number of .wav files =%
  ) else for /f %%E in ('dir /b /a-d "%%B[*.wav"^|find /c /v ""') do (
    flac.exe -0 --picture="%source%\%%~nA.jpg" --tag-from-file="CUESHEET=%source%\%%~nA.cue" -T "ALBUMARTIST=%%C" -T "DISCNUMBER=%%D" -T "TOTALDISCS=%%E" "%source%\%%A"
  )
)

popd
```

Again, you can add an IF to the outer loop to proceed only if the .flac file does not already exist in the destination.

Comment: EDIT - Added a simpler solution using JREPL.BAT

Comment: Tested the first solution (without JREPL.BAT utility), worked in every case of mine. It's quite more than I've expected. Now I gotta follow the code step-by-step and understand this magic for future needs. Thank You very much for the whole solution with explanations. This will surely help me comprehend the concept of working with CMD.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
PUSHD "%destdir%"
:: Find all .jpgs where there is a .wav and .cue with the same name
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d *.jpg') DO IF EXIST "%%~na.wav" IF EXIST "%%~na.cue" (
 FOR %%b IN (input albumartist discnumber totaldiscs) DO SET "%%b="
 SET "input=%%~na"
 FOR /f "delims=-" %%b IN ("%%a") DO SET "albumartist=%%b"
 FOR /f "tokens=2delims=[]" %%b IN ("%%a") DO SET "disc=%%b"
 IF DEFINED disc (
  FOR /f "tokens=1delims=[]" %%d IN ("%%a") DO FOR /f %%c IN ('dir /b "%%d[*.wav"') DO SET /a totaldiscs+=1
 )
 CALL :gflac
)

POPD

GOTO :EOF

:gflac
:: remove trailing spaces from INPUT
IF "%albumartist:~-1%"==" " SET "albumartist=%albumartist:~0,-1%"&GOTO gflac
:: presume default for disc and totaldiscs
IF DEFINED disc (FOR /f "tokens=2" %%d IN ("%disc%") DO SET /a disc=%%d) ELSE (SET /a disc=1)
IF NOT DEFINED totaldiscs SET /a totaldiscs=1
ECHO( flac.exe -0 --picture="D:\Music\%input%.jpg" --tag-from-file="CUESHEET=D:\Music\%input%.cue" -T "ALBUMARTIST=%albumartist%" -T "DISCNUMBER=%discnumber%" -T "TOTALDISCS=%totaldiscs%" "D:\Music\%input%.wav"
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the setting of `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The above will merely `echo` the required `flac` line. I left it as you posted but set the scant test data you posted up as I interpret it (ie. there is a set of 3 files) on my U: drive.

Sadly, you've given us insufficient information. I've assumed that you need all three files to be present, and the default for `totaldiscs` is 1.

First, look for all `.jpgs`, and if there is a corresponding `.wav` and `.cue` then process for `flac` generation as follows:

- Set `input` to the name part of the `.jpg` found
- set `albumartist` to the first part of the filename, up to the `-`
- get the `[disc n]` string if it's present
- count the number of `.wav`s that start with the filename up to the `[`
- generate the `flac` line.

Within the generation of the `flac` line, we strip off the trailing spaces from `input`, convert `disc n` to `n` or set disc to 1 (although this information may not be needed), and set the totaldiscs to 1 if it's not been calculated.

You don't say what `flac` produces as output, but I'd suggest that you further gate that filetype so that the procedure doesn't run if the `%input%.finalproductwhateverthatis` file is present.

[edited per dbenham's comments]

Comment: Some bugs: Your outer loop is looking for files in the destination folder. Your artist name has a trailing space.

Comment: @dbenham - but you omitted the `[` missing in `"%%d*.wav"` which should be `"%%d[*.wav"`. Artist name with trailing space? Er, no. The first active line in `:gflac` removes that or them. Directory names - it's just a name. User uses `D:\Music\` My `D:` drive gets turned on on Monday nights for backups. Just left OP's original line in and used my test directory `u:\destdir` as a well - source of data. OP would no doubt use `D:\Music`

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence. Your trailing space removal logic is flawed - I tested. Your code will fail if destination is not "D\Music" because outer loop looks in destination.

Comment: @dbenham : yes - better if the strip-trailing-spaces is applied to the correct variable. Fixed by edit. Your critique didn't mention the missing `[` that's required in `"%%d[*.wav"`